# How to create multi conditions "if" function in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-formatting, vba

[image]

I assume x is the number I'm going to analyze and "y" is as "male" or "female" and "z" is as age group.
x is a number that the result will be "underweight", healthy " or overweight". but x which is actually the BPI is not the same for male and female. eg, if x = 21 then depends on gender and age it would be categorized as either "underweight", "healthy " or overweight".

```
 Function BAI(x As Integer, y As String, z As Integer) As String


 If x < 21 And y = "female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"

 Elseif 22 <= x <= 33 And y = "Female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 34 <= x <= 38 And y = "Female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "overweight"

ElseIf x >= 39 And y = "Female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "OBESE"

ElseIf x <= 23 And y = "female" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"

ElseIf 24 <= x <= 35 And y = "female" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 36 <= x <= 41 And y = "female" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "Overweight"

ElseIf x >= 42 And y = "female" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "OBESE"

ElseIf x <= 25 And y = "female" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"

ElseIf 26 <= x <= 38 And y = "female" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 39 <= x <= 43 And y = "female" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "Overweight"

ElseIf x >= 44 And y = "female" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "obese"

ElseIf x <= 8 And y = "male" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "Underweight"

ElseIf 9 <= x <= 21 And y = "male" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 22 <= x <= 26 And y = "male" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "overweight"

ElseIf x >= 27 And y = "male" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "OBESE"

ElseIf x <= 11 And y = "male" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"

ElseIf 12 <= x <= 23 And y = "male" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 24 <= x <= 28 And y = "male" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "Overweight"

ElseIf x >= 29 And y = "male" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "OBESE"

ElseIf x <= 13 And y = "male" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"

ElseIf 14 <= x <= 25 And y = "male" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 26 <= x <= 30 And y = "male" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "Overweight"

 End If

 End Function
```

Comment: You can nest up to 64 IF's, that should be more than enough for just ten conditions. If you decide to state your real problem, there may be more efficient solutions, but probably you should post in the SuperUser forum

Comment: Function BAI(x As Integer, y As String, z As Integer) As String
If x < 21 And y = "female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
  BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"
    ElseIf 22 <= x <= 33 And y = "Female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
        BAI = "Healthy"                                               ElseIf 34 <= x <= 38 And y = "Female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
        BAI = "overweight"
    ElseIf x >= 39 And y = "Female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
        BAI = "OBESE"

Comment: Your comment does not clarify your problem, to me. And it seems to be VBA and not Excel. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sry for inconvenient , i tried to make it clear please check it out.

Comment: Did you read the references I suggested?  Please re-read the one about providing an example.  Also, what language is your function in?  If it is VBA, then `20 <= z <= 39` is not valid syntax.  Should be something like `20 <= z And z <=39`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld , yes it is VBA ,I see that syntax might be the case, because in some numbers i'm getting the right answer and in some not, let me try this first...tnx

Comment: @RonRosenfeld that was not the problem, i changed'em all but still not working. i spent more than 8 hours to solve this but still nothing...

Comment: Your problem remains unclear to me. `get wrong answer sometimes` is all I understand. Unless you can clarify, I won't be able to help. I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have chosen to provide.

Comment: i couldn't solve it and i do not know anymore how to express myself and very frustrated. i sent my formula and i attach the image, no idea how to express myself. i have 3 conditional variables to analyze a numeric cell (x) into a string like (a,b,c,d) . Age ,Gender and X. The age is 3 conditional ( e,f) , gender is 2 conditional (m,f) and x is 12 conditional for each specific gender. i just need to know a function or a defined user function to be able define 3 conditions.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i do not know how to say this, thanks you. i do really need help. i'm sure i just do not know a tiny detail. it took me my whole 2 days. any advice would be greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You need to review your logic.  You require that `x` be an `integer`. You have no provision for `female`, `z = 20-39` and `x=21` or `x=39`.  You have no category for `Obese` with `male` and `z = 60-79`.   If it were me, I would construct lookup tables.  Easier to follow the logic, and to maintain if you should want to make minor changes.  (Or, you could hire someone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a new answer given the edited question.

If you're going to go the If-Then-Else route, then I would recommend breaking down your logic into groups.  I tried, but I'm not familiar with your field so I may not have done it perfectly:

1. First, test if the person is male or female.
2. Second, test to see which range their Age is within.
3. Third, test to see which range their BPI is within.

Also, for readability, I would recommend renaming your variables to something more meaningful.  I renamed "x" to "BPI", "y" to "Gender", and "z" to "Age".

---

Edit: For the case-sensitive "male" and "female", I've added the `UCase` function to the code below. It converts a string to all uppercase, which allows it to be compared to an all uppercase string.  For example, "MaLe" would be converted to "MALE", and then compared to "MALE".  In other words, this should eliminate the case-sensitivity from the gender portion of the function.

Also, for possible spaces before/after the gender, using the `Trim` function will eliminate them.  So, `Trim("Male   ")` becomes just `"Male"` (no spaces).

---

Look at the following and see if it's more what you're looking for:

```
Function BAI(BPI As Integer, Gender As String, Age As Integer) As String
If UCase(Trim(Gender)) = "FEMALE" Then
    If 20 <= Age And Age <= 39 Then
        If BPI <= 21 Then BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"
        If 22 <= BPI And BPI <= 33 Then BAI = "Healthy"
        If 34 <= BPI And BPI <= 38 Then BAI = "Overweight"
        If BPI >= 39 Then BAI = "OBESE"
    ElseIf 40 <= Age And Age <= 59 Then
        If BPI <= 23 Then BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"
        If 24 <= BPI And BPI <= 35 Then BAI = "Healthy"
        If 36 <= BPI And BPI <= 41 Then BAI = "Overweight"
        If BPI >= 42 Then BAI = "OBESE"
    ElseIf 60 <= Age And Age <= 79 Then
        If BPI <= 25 Then BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"
        If 26 <= BPI And BPI <= 38 Then BAI = "Healthy"
        If 39 <= BPI And BPI <= 43 Then BAI = "Overweight"
        If BPI >= 44 Then BAI = "OBESE"
    Else
        BAI = "Error - Age outside acceptable range"
    End If
ElseIf UCase(Trim(Gender)) = "MALE" Then
    If 20 <= Age And Age <= 39 Then
        If BPI <= 8 Then BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"
        If 9 <= BPI And BPI <= 21 Then BAI = "Healthy"
        If 22 <= BPI And BPI <= 26 Then BAI = "Overweight"
        If BPI >= 27 Then BAI = "OBESE"
    ElseIf 40 <= Age And Age <= 59 Then
        If BPI <= 11 Then BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"
        If 12 <= BPI And BPI <= 23 Then BAI = "Healthy"
        If 24 <= BPI And BPI <= 28 Then BAI = "Overweight"
        If BPI >= 29 Then BAI = "OBESE"
    ElseIf 60 <= Age And Age <= 79 Then
        If BPI <= 13 Then BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"
        If 14 <= BPI And BPI <= 25 Then BAI = "Healthy"
        If 26 <= BPI And BPI <= 30 Then BAI = "Overweight"
        If BPI >= 31 Then BAI = "OBESE"
    Else
        BAI = "Error - Age outside acceptable range"
    End If
Else
    BAI = "Error - Choose male or female"
End If
End Function
```

Comment: you are awesome!! the best, I spent almost full 2 days working on this. i used our both function VBA but you know what i realized that may make you laugh. in gender section i had a list "Female" and "Male". if you see in the function i wrote in some area is "female" and some "Female" capital and small letter!!!! you guess right, i am stupid... also when i ran yours in my cell i had "Female" but you wrote "female" so it did not return me a correct answer. i just found out how CUTE VBA is about spaces and letters. by the way you are the best. thank you so much for your time .

Comment: @MehdiFit Glad I could help.  I've edited the answer to make the gender case-sensitivity perform better.  Using the `UCase` function allows for any case input (e.g., "fEMaLe") to return true when compared to "FEMALE".  So, `UCase("fEMaLe") = "FEMALE"`.  I've also included the `Trim` function to eliminate any extra spaces before/after the gender input. Using `UCase` and `Trim` will allow the function to handle an input like `  FEMale    ` and still work.